# How to open and edit .obj file

Tags: file, portability

I have downloaded a portable data file from a website, and would like to be able to edit it, to understand its structure and to generate such files myself.

http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=ga4a4462424e50b70999210576591a13bb562d9009

Can someone give me a clue where to start and what to open it with?

Thanks!

Comment: An .obj file is typically the intermediate output between the compiler and linker, and therefore isn't able to be "opened and edited". As far as your link goes, please edit and post an actual link so people can see where it leads; it's inconsiderate enough expecting us to leave this site to figure out what you're actually asking without also expecting us to click a blind link.

Comment: sorry, I thought it was a better way to post here. Edited

Comment: As I said, an `.obj` (object) file is normally produced by running a compiler; that object file, along with any other object files and required library files are then passed to the linker, which then creates an executable file. To alter an object file, you modify the source code that was compiled to create it in the first place and then recompile it. There's no way to edit it, read it, modify it, or anything else; as far as generating the file yourself, write a compiler that produces the proper format object file. How to do so is way beyond the scope of anything answerable here.

Comment: I just checked the link you provided, and it is indeed an object file as described in my other two comments. It's not a "data file", and isn't something you can just open, read, understand, and edit. Sorry, but you're out of luck here.